# Jacobson radical of $A[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring, and let $A[x]$ be the ring of polynomials in one variable over $A$. Is the Jacobson ideal of $A[x]$ (here denoted with $J$) the zero ideal in general?

I know that $f(x)\in J$ (if and) only if $1-f(x)g(x)$ is a unit for every $g(x)\in A[x]$. But for any non-zero $f(x)$, choosing $g(x)=x$, we have $\operatorname {deg}(1-xf(x))\gt 0$, so that $1-xf(x)$ isn't a unit. It follows that $J=(0)$, and so the nilradical is $(0)$ too.

Is this proof correct? It seems a too strict result for a general ring like $A[x]$, and in fact the text of the exercise only asked to prove that $J$ is equal to the nilradical (not that they are the zero ideal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful! For instance, if $A=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then $2x+1$ has positive degree, but it is a unit in $A[x]$. In fact, we have $(2x+1)^2=4x^2+4x+1=1$.

The fact that $\deg(f)>0$ implies that $f$ is not a unit, is not true in general. (It is true, however, if $A$ is a field.) One way to generalize that statement is the following (which is Exercise 1 from Chapter 1 of Atiyah-Macdonald):

> Let $A$ be a ring, and $A[x]$ the ring of polynomials. Then $f=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$ is a unit if and only if $a_0$ is a unit in $A$, and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you so I would proceed in this way: if $f\in J$, then $1-xf\in A[x]$ must be a unit. So using the exercise you mentioned (that is the number 1.21) we get that ($1$ must be invertible and) the coefficients of $f$ are all nilpotent. The exercise 1.22 says that $f$ is nilpotent, and so we get also $J\subseteq \sqrt{0}$.

Comment: That sounds correct!

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, if $A$ is not an integral domain then polynomials of positive degree can still be invertible. In general, a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ in $A[x]$ is invertible if and only if $a_0\in A^{\times}$ and $a_1,...,a_n$ are nilpotent.

For example, take $A=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. Then the polynomial $(2+4\mathbb{Z})x$ belongs to the Jacobson radical of $A[x]$. Indeed, take any $g\in A[x]$. Then the free term of $(1+4\mathbb{Z})-(2+4\mathbb{Z})xg(x)$ is a unit, while the other coefficients are nilpotent. (as they are divisible by the nilpotent elements $2+4\mathbb{Z}$)